# Workflow recursive submission from experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, workflow

Sitecore 8.2.

We have a "Data" folder under each page item in which components which are on the page are stored.

We currently have only 1 workflow which we use called "Simple workflow".

When a page is submitted via the Experience Editor, it automatically submits any/all descendants so that items in the Data folder will get moved in the workflow.

The problem comes when the Home page is edited and submitted in the workflow. Because the recursive nature of the submission, every single item in the whole tree gets submitted at the same time and I don't know how to prevent that.

The workflow (and everything else) was initially setup by a 3rd party consulting company who helped us get everything going.

How do I allow a submission of the page and the page's related items from the Experience Editor? Currently it submits all child items 1 deep

Here is a screenshot of a portion of the content tree
[image: Screenshot of content tree]

UPDATE:
After further testing, I found additional information which only seems more confusing to me: the depth of the recursive submission seems to be only 1 with the exception of the Data folder, where it goes at least 2 deep. See images below. I can also find no custom code developed related to the auto submission action:
[image: Test Scenario]
[image: Test Scenario submission results]

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: Is the workflow using a standard action (or one with parameters you can configure), or is it purely custom code? My guess is that you'll need access to that action's source code to change it...

Comment: @PeterProcházka, It's version 8.2

Comment: @DanSinclair I'm not sure how to tell. I don't know about how the workflows are put together beyond the very basic information readily available on the web and in the developer training. If you have a good reference you can link, it would be appreciated.

Comment: In Sitecore, go to `/sitecore/System/Workflows` and look for the workflow your items are using (you can find the one selected by selecting an example item in the Content Editor, showing Standard Fields and scrolling down to the Workflow section; the `Default Workflow` field should be set to the one you care about). Expand that workflow and look at the states (the first level of items) and the actions (the items below the states).

Comment: Is there a way you can show a screen shot of how you have your items structured?  I'm assuming that the home page is the parent of the data folder (and probably other folders)?  My guess is we will need to write something custom to target only the folder or data templates you want

Comment: @Mikeyp I added a screenshot. Every page/folder that is added has a "Data" folder by default. Originally, the homepage didn't even have a workflow attached, I linked it to the only workflow we use, but I think this is probably why consulting company that set the whole site up originally didn't give the Home page a workflow...

Comment: This is most likely a custom workflow action, [something like this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-82-workflow-bundling-jamie-scott/). Although Sitecore 8.2 [added better workflow support](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/09/05/sitecore-8-2-managing-datasource-components-and-workflow-from-the-experience-editor/), this is not the standard behaviour. The solution is to update your code to submit **the current page and it's datasources** only, but that requires a lot debugging than is possible here on StackExchange.

Comment: @jammyKam is correct.  based on your screen shot that is what you would have to do. Maybe look at your structure and see if there is a better way to do it.  For example, in my case, every item that has related items has it's own _resources folder where those data sourced items are stored.  This way, when the parent items is published, I can safely publish the item and its children without publishing the entire site.

I believe that sitecore 9 supports publishing related items of related items.  This might solve your problem but publishing operations will take longer.

Comment: @Mikeyp The issue is not just about publishing, it's also about those datasource items being in workflow, and moving through the whole workflow process together, as a single unit. Which is why this goes into a discussion, and not a good fit for a Q&A as the questions stands, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is actually default behavior.

> See: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/09/05/sitecore-8-2-managing-datasource-components-and-workflow-from-the-experience-editor/

Related items on the page will be submitted when the page is submitted to the workflow from the Experience Editor. This is configured in the `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config` file via the `WebEdit.AffectWorkflowForDatasourceItems` setting.

To those who tried to answer my question, I apologize. When I posted my question, I was thinking that the additional pages that were being submitted were not related to the home page, but it turns out that they **are** related items.

The pages that were getting submitted are datasources for one of more components on the page being submitted. I didn't realize that and therefore you had no way to know.